# Read text file into dictionary without duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

I am reading a text file into a dictionary using a short Linq expression

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
var dictionary = lines.Select(line => line.Split(';')).ToDictionary(keyValue => keyValue[0], bits => bits[1]);
```

This works just fine as long as I dont have duplicate keys in my text file. Is there a short way to filter those without going the long way and iterating over the lines[] array?

Comment: What do you *want* to happen if there are duplicates? I can think of at least 5 different options off the top of my head. (First wins, last wins, exception, make each value a list, use some sort of separator.)

Comment: Just do not add them to the dictionary :)

Comment: So you want a "first entry wins" approach, silently ignoring data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` first:

```
var dictionary = lines.Select(line => line.Split(';'))
    .GroupBy(arr => arr[0])
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First()[1]);
```

This selects the first element of each duplicate, if that's not desired you have to change `g.First` accordingly. You could for example separate the values with comma:

```
var dictionary = lines.Select(line => line.Split(';'))
    .GroupBy(arr => arr[0])
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => string.Join(",", g.Select(arr=> arr[1])));
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tim Schmelter. For my specific case, removing blank lines, I used your code + `.Where()`:

```
var dictionary = lines.Select(line => line.Split(';'))
    .Where(line => line.Length == 2)
    .GroupBy(arr => arr[0])
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First()[1]);
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way.
Thanks